Invocation/utterance phrasing
I'm developing a custom Alexa skill and I am at the stage where I need to decide how to invoke my application with the most natural phrasing.
My application adds items that you specify to add to a third party 'watchlist' via an API. This works successfully.
Testing with 'foo bar' which I have configured as the invocation words.
I WANT to say "Add {item} to {foo bar}" using utterance 'add {item} to' but Alexa responds with "I couldn't find a list called foo bar. Should I create one?"
I tried with 'push {item} to' and she responds "Sorry, I don't know that one."
I'm pulling my hair out trying to derive a suitable phrase, can anyone please advise how I can override 'add'? I can't use the words 'watchlist' or 'list' either, even though I'd also consider "Add {item} to {foo watchlist}" or something similar.
It only works with something like "Ask {foo bar} to add {item}", which doesn't sound very natural, is this as good as it gets?

The best I can achieve so far is using invocation words "foo for" and utterance "{item}" on it's own, to make the phrase "Ask {foo for} {item}". Can I use something like 'Microsoft for' or 'for Microsoft' as my invocation? The hint suggests that it's okay but I don't want to fail certification.
"Brand names are only allowed if you provide proof of rights in the testing instructions or if you use the brand name in a referential manner that doesn’t imply ownership (examples of terms that can be added to a brand name for referential usage: unofficial, unauthorized, fan, fandom, for, about)."
